# What is the purpose and roles of each files made with with the EasyRSA? (used for OpenVPN)

Tags: vpn, openvpn, certificate, rsa

I'm setting up an OpenVPN server on my computer.
Many of the tutorials dedicate a significant portion of the article for RSA key creation, but none of them really explains what each of the files are for and how they work. Searching about RSA gives me explanations for the RSA encryption, but what I really want to know is what each of the files do (such as ca.crt/ca.key, server.crt/server.key, ta.crt/ta.key), rather than how the encryption works. Sure I can just follow the tutorial step by step and make the software work, but I'd like to go through the process with more understanding of what is really going on.

Comment: It’s in the name though? Certificates (*.crt) and keys (*.key). The way they’re using is in the RSA description. There’s only `ta.key`, by the way.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks. Maybe I was just giving too much thoughts on them...